# Nested Fields form is getting an error when I try to add placeholder association record in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I have two Rails models: `workout`, `measurable`.  When I go to my form to edit a workout I'm getting the following error.

**Error when visiting workouts#edit**

```
*** ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation Exception: TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'value', table 'bane-development.dbo.measurables'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.: EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [measurables] ([measurable_type_id], [workout_id], [created_at], [updated_at], [import_key]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)', N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 datetime, @3 datetime, @4 int', @0 = 3, @1 = 689349, @2 = '05-29-2018 09:22:45.206', @3 = '05-29-2018 09:22:45.206', @4 = -1
```

What I'm trying to do is populate my Rails `workout` form to have options for the user to fill out various measurables to add to workout.  However, I don't want them to save to the database if they do not have a value.  But when the following line executes `self.measurables << Measurable.new(measurable_type_id: measurable_type.id, order_by: 1, import_key: -1)` - it seems it's trying to save to the database when I don't want it to yet... I just want it to give the user fields to input data if they choose.  How can I get it to add the association to the form but not save the record until I update the `workout` object?

**workout.rb**

```
class Workout < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :remove_blank_measurables

  has_many :measurables, inverse_of: :workout
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :measurables, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: proc {|m| m[:value].blank?}

  def add_missing_measurable_types
    MeasurableType.workout_observations.each do |measurable_type|
      if !self.has_measurable_type?(measurable_type)
        self.measurables << Measurable.new(measurable_type_id: measurable_type.id, order_by: 1, import_key: -1)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

**measurable.rb**

```
class Measurable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workout
end
```

**workouts#edit**

```
def edit
  @workout.add_missing_measurable_types
end
```

Comment: We need db schema for 'bane-development.dbo.measurables', it seems there is a 'null: false' on a 'value' column. This 'value' column is missing in your 'Measurable.new'

Comment: @D1ceWard, Correct, it's missing from my Measurable.new - because I want to have the Measurable Types show up for the form, but I don't want to add a value to it yet. I want to leave that up to the user. For instance, a workout can have 3 measurable types (Height, Weight, and Speed). If a use opens a workout where they've only previously filled out the Height field, I want to add the Weight & Speed fields to the form incase they want to add those. But I don't want to save them to the database if the value is blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

> **collection<<(object, …)**
>   Adds one or more objects to the collection by creating associations in the join table (collection.push and collection.concat are aliases to this method). **Note that this operation instantly fires update SQL without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object**, unless the parent object is a new record.

'<<' (shovel operator) fires update/save, you should instead use

```
self.measurables.new(measurable_type_id: measurable_type.id, order_by: 1, import_key: -1)
```

Comment: Thanks!  And I appreciate the explanation of the << operator and how it will execute update/save.  Your suggested edit also worked like a charm.